# Forbidden in official image Docker PHP

Tags: php, apache, docker

I'm testing the official image docker PHP:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 --name test php:7-apache
```

Then, I test http://localhost:8000, I find this:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 --name test php:7-apache -v "$PWD":/var/www/html
```

Go to your project folder and run the above command or replace $PWD with your project directory. -v will sync your project to the docker container.

Or create a Docker file and use copy to run your project within the container.

Any one of the above will solve your problem.
The probable reason for the error is the fact that there is no project to render.

Comment: Best solution but on systems with selinux you'll need to append `:Z` to the `-v` argument (it becomes `...w/html:Z`) in order to change the selinux tags accordingly. ([more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594643/docker-php5-6-apache-403-because-search-permissions-are-missing-on-a-component/58528872#58528872))

Answer (score 3):

There's no hello world included with this image, `/var/www/html/` is empty so there's no content to view. You need to bundle your own code in as the [page on this image instructs](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/):

> We recommend that you add a custom php.ini configuration. COPY it into
>   /usr/local/etc/php by adding one more line to the Dockerfile above and
>   running the same commands to build and run:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

Comment: This is my php.ini https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production, but it's not working.

Comment: which folder contains the source?

Comment: Whichever folder you put it in?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have files, it's behavior is normal.
But if you have, probabily is problem of permissions.

Error 403 is likely permission problem.
Inside container, run command:

```
$ ls -lsh
```

If letter 'r' (read) don't, you can try:

```
$ chmod +r <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit/add the .htaccess rewrite rule:

.htaccess

```
...
RewriteRule /
...
```