# Docker php:5.6-apache 403 (because search permissions are missing on a component of the path)

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Files tree:

```
├── docker-compose.yml 
├── Dockerfile 
└── www 
    └── index.html
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
ADD ./www /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php5_6:
    build: .
    ports :
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - ./www:/var/www/html/
```

Try to start docker

```
$ docker-compose up
[core:error] [pid 17] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.19.0.1:53514] AH00035: access to /index.html denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/index.html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

In browser http://localhost 403 page

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I know my answer is late, but someone else will get some help from this  answer.

Use `:z` or `:Z` option at the end to mount your volume with enough permissions. To be exact this will add a selinux rule `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /path/to/volume`

```
version: '2'
services:
php7_2:
  build: .
  ports :
   - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - "./www:/var/www/html/:Z"
```

Read more details at,

1. http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/
2. [Permission denied on accessing host directory in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288616/permission-denied-on-accessing-host-directory-in-docker)

Comment: This also works with `podman run`'s `-v` option to mount volumes. Just append `:Z`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that apache doesn't have the appropriate access to the html directory. In particular it likely needs execute permission in addition to read permissions.

Try adding `RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/` to your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is enabled SELinux. Disable in /etc/selinux/conf will solve it.

Comment: This may work, but PraAnj's answer is much better.